# Why doesn't this OpenCV masking function iterate?

Tags: python, opencv, if-statement, image-processing, iteration

I wrote an algorithm in Python OpenCV to find certain targets, but sometimes these targets are hard to find so I made this if-else statement to just output 'target not found' when it fails to find the target. I'm iterating over 1000 images and calling the algo on them, but i get this error:

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

on 6th line of the code below:

```
def image_data(img):
    img3 = masking (img)
    if img3 is None:
        print "target not found"
    else:
        cent, MOI = find_center(img3)
        if cent == 0 or MOI == 0:
        print 'target not found'
        else:
        return cent[0],cent[1],MOI
```

I understand it means it did't find the image, but why doesn't it just go on to the next image and print error statement?

Comment: @berak Since you're the boss on this, do you happen to know?

Comment: `find_center(img3)` returns `None`, add the code for `find_center`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham added
 if centroid == None or MOI == None:
            print 'target not found' 
to find_center function and it still gives me the same error

Comment: try http://pastebin.com/jyRypusF

Comment: @PadraicCunningham fval not defined since i'm not using MATLAB

Comment: doh, typo, should just be val

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72440/discussion-between-shideh-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function sometimes returns None so you cannot unpack variables from None:

```
In [1]: def f(i):
   ...:     if i > 2:
   ...:         return "foo","bar"
   ...:     

In [2]: a,b = f(3)

In [3]: a,b
Out[3]: ('foo', 'bar')

In [4]: a,b = f(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-54f2476b15d0> in <module>()
----> 1 a,b = f(1)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Check if the return value is None before unpacking:

```
def image_data(img):
    img3 = masking (img)
    if img3 is None:
        print("target not found")
    else:
        val = find_center(img3)
        if val:
            cent, MOI = val
            return cent[0],cent[1],MOI
        else:
            print('target not found')
```

Or use a `try/except`:

```
def image_data(img):
    img3 = masking (img)
    if img3 is None:
        print("target not found")
    else:
        try:
            cent, MOI = find_center(img3)
            return cent[0], cent[1], MOI
        except TypeError:
            print('target not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to assign None to a list of values.

```
>>> a, b = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

To do this correctly try with:

```
cent, MOI = find_center(img3) or (None, None)
```

With this, if find_center returns a correct value, it will be assigned to cent and MOI. If it returns a None, None will be assigned to both cent and MOI.